# Should systemd be running as a sub-process of itself?

Tags: dependencies, systemd, process, system-monitor

I just noticed in System Monitor that systemd is running as pid 1 AND that within that process it is listed as a dependent process of itself, running again under process 1 as pid 933 and with another set of various processes running as dependents of 933.  Is this normal or something that indicates a problem?

```
● user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
             └─10-oomd-user-service-defaults.conf, timeout.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-12-17 09:29:17 CST; 1h 48min ago
       Docs: man:user@.service(5)
   Main PID: 933 (systemd)
     Status: "Startup finished in 2.088s."
      Tasks: 643
     Memory: 10.8G
        CPU: 1h 28min 25.187s
```

Comment: I think it's probably your `systemd --user` instance - does `systemctl status user@$(id -u).service` report the same PID?

Comment: owner of pid1 was root  and  myusername listed as owner of pid 933

Comment: also the respective commandlines:  pid1:  /sbin/init/ splash      pid 933: /lib/systemd/systemd/ --user

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add + format that information into your question. Please run the systemctl --status command as your ordinary `myusername` not as root.

Comment: I did that wrong.  I'm fixing it now.

Comment: ● user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
             └─10-oomd-user-service-defaults.conf, timeout.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-12-17 09:29:17 CST; 1h 48min ago
       Docs: man:user@.service(5)
   Main PID: 933 (systemd)
     Status: "Startup finished in 2.088s."
      Tasks: 643
     Memory: 10.8G
        CPU: 1h 28min 25.187s

Comment: TypeError: this.actor is null
_syncEnabled@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:138:25
nStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:150:35
_makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:151:22
_easeActorProperty/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:317:60
_destroyWindowDone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1596:21
onStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1564:39
_makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:151:2  _easeActor/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:240:64